# Subtracting 2 columns from different tables with the same ID

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables `TblAddToInventory` and `TblWithdrawnFromInventory`. Both have `ProductID` and `Quantity`. When a withdrawal is made, naturally the Inventory should deduct the quantity of items but only items that have been withdrawn. Example:

> TblAddToInventory

```
ProductID | Quantity | Amount | Date

1           2          2.00     7/7/2012

2           3          3.00     7/7/2012

3           4          4.00     7/7/2012

2           2          2.00     7/8/2012

3           3          3.00     7/8/2012
```

> TblWithdrawnFromInventory

```
ProductID | Quantity | Amount | Date

2           4          4.00     7/9/2012

3           5          5.00     7/10/2012
```

With this, when I join the two tables and deduct the specific columns, I should have a `DataGridView` using C# with this data:

```
ProductID | Quantity | Amount 

1           2          2.00

2           1          1.00

3           2          2.00
```

I know how to use `SUM` and `JOIN` but I just don't know how to create a syntax that will subtract two columns from different tables with the same ID.

I don't know if this is the right way but what I have in mind is `SUM` all from `TblAddToInventory` using `GROUP BY` then `SUM` all from `TblWithdrawnFromInventory` using `GROUP BY` and then `SUBTRACT` columns from `TblAddToInventory` and `TblWithdrawnFromInventory` using `GROUP BY`. But I don't think that's a good idea. Can you help?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not make it an InventoryActivity table that can have changes with positive or negative amounts? Still, you can use a UNION between two select queries, and then sum the results of those two queries.

Comment: you can use linq or lambda to select values on each row with the same id

Comment: I am not that adept with sql yet. Can you give me the syntax for the select command?

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to use SUM and JOIN but I just don't know how to create a
>   syntax that will subtract two columns from different tables with the
>   same ID.

**This is code how you to do this:**

```
 SELECT inventory.ProductId, 
            inventory.Quantity - ISNULL(withdrawal.Quantity,0) AS Quantity, 
            inventory.Amount - ISNULL(withdrawal.Amount,0) AS Amount
        FROM (
            SELECT ProductId, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
            FROM TblAddToInventory
            GROUP BY ProductId
        ) AS inventory
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT ProductId, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
            FROM TblWithdrawnFromInventory
            GROUP BY ProductId
        ) AS withdrawal ON inventory.ProductId = withdrawal.ProductId
```

Comment: Thanks trungtin1710. But your code doesn't give me the right result. This is what I have came up with:                                                             SELECT     TblAddToInventory.ProductID AS [Product ID], SUM(TblAddToInventory.Quantity) - SUM(TblWithdrawal.Quantity) AS Quantity, SUM(TblAddToInventory.Amount) - SUM(TblWithdrawal.Amount) AS Amount
FROM TblAddToInventory LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      TblWithdrawal ON TblAddToInventory.ProductID = TblWithdrawal.ProductID
GROUP BY TblAddToInventory.ProductID

Comment: It gives me the right values but for those ProductID that has no withdrawals, it gives me a null value. What I need is to give me the summed amount of the ProductID that is in the TblAddToInventory if there is no deduction from TblWithdrawnFromInventory

Comment: "for those ProductID that has no withdrawals, it gives me a null value"  I think it will OK with your case, in your example data, my code can sum productid=1

Comment: It gives me a null value with ProductID 1 instead of 2 and null value in Amount instead of 2.00 because there is no withdrawal to sum with that ProductID. I am using my code that I have created in my comment coz I get an error when I use your code but that is where I got my idea from though.

Answer (score 0):

## Preparation:

**-- create temp table with the data, cast the first row's date to set the proper data type**

```
select * into #tblAddToInventory from (
select 1 as ProductID, 2 as Quantity, 2.00 as Amount, cast('7/7/2012' as date) as [Date]
union all select 2 as ProductID, 3 as Quantity, 3.00 as Amount, '7/7/2012' as Date 
union all select 3 as ProductID, 4 as Quantity, 4.00 as Amount, '7/7/2012' as Date 
union all select 2 as ProductID, 2 as Quantity, 2.00 as Amount, '7/8/2012' as Date 
union all select 3 as ProductID, 3 as Quantity, 3.00 as Amount, '7/8/2012' as Date 
) a
```

**-- create temp table with the data, cast the first row's date to set the proper data type**

```
select * into #tblWithdrawnFromInventory from (
select 2 as ProductID, 4 as Quantity, 4.00 as Amount, cast('7/9/2012' as date) as [Date]
union all select 3 as ProductID, 5 as Quantity, 5.00 as Amount, '7/10/2012' as Date 
) b
```

**-- verify the data looks correct**

```
select * from #tblAddToInventory
--    ProductID   Quantity    Amount      Date
--    ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
--    1           2           2.00        2012-07-07
--    2           3           3.00        2012-07-07
--    3           4           4.00        2012-07-07
--    2           2           2.00        2012-07-08
--    3           3           3.00        2012-07-08
```

**-- verify the data looks correct**

```
select * from #tblWithdrawnFromInventory
--    ProductID   Quantity    Amount      Date
--    ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
--    2           4           4.00        2012-07-09
--    3           5           5.00        2012-07-10
```

## Begin solution:

**-- use Union All to join the queries, and multiply the second query by -1 to make them negative**

```
select * from #tblAddToInventory union all 
select ProductID, (Quantity * -1) as Quantity, Amount, Date from #tblWithdrawnFromInventory

--    ProductID   Quantity    Amount      Date
--    ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
--    1           2           2.00        2012-07-07
--    2           3           3.00        2012-07-07
--    3           4           4.00        2012-07-07
--    2           2           2.00        2012-07-08
--    3           3           3.00        2012-07-08
--    2           -4          4.00        2012-07-09
--    3           -5          5.00        2012-07-10

select ProductID, sum(Quantity) as Quantity, sum(Amount) as Amount from (
    select * from #tblAddToInventory union all 
    select ProductID, (Quantity * -1) as Quantity, (Amount * -1) as Amount, Date from #tblWithdrawnFromInventory
) joinedData
where [Date] >= '7/6/2012' and [Date] <= '7/11/2012'
group by ProductID

--    ProductID   Quantity    Amount
--    ----------- ----------- -----------
--    1           2           2.00
--    2           1           1.00
--    3           2           2.00
```

**-- delete temp tables**

```
drop table #tblAddToInventory
drop table #tblWithdrawnFromInventory
```